# Requesting permission as an option

Tags: android

Hey I am using an API level below 23.

I want to ask users in app if they want to enable read contacts so I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

I am trying to use this code to ask for permission at run time

```
    private void checkPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {
            Log.d("ABC", "1");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        }else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            Log.d("ABC", "2");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("ABC", "GRANTED");

            } else {
                Log.d("ABC", "Denied");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But if i do not include the permission it automatically declines the request, and if i do it never needs to ask.

How can I make it so contacts are not included in the app permissions, but I can ask for them during run time? Thanks

Comment: You cant do that, you have to add required permissions in manifest.

Comment: @AkshayBhat so there is no way to ask for permissions during run-time without needing them during install?

Comment: No, you cant add permission in manifest during runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to ask for permission that doesn't exist in Android Manifest.

A good example ---->  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions